# How resolve WARN when run ansible: [WARNING]: Skipping plugin as it seems to be invalid?

Tags: 16.04, ansible

When I run ansible command, like this:

```
ansible -i host all -m ping
```

I got this warnings:

```
[WARNING]: Skipping plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/foreman.py) as it seems to be invalid: from_buffer() cannot return the address of the raw string
within a str or unicode or bytearray object
[WARNING]: Skipping plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/grafana_annotations.py) as it seems to be invalid: from_buffer() cannot return the address of the
raw string within a str or unicode or bytearray object
[WARNING]: Skipping plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/hipchat.py) as it seems to be invalid: from_buffer() cannot return the address of the raw string
within a str or unicode or bytearray object
[WARNING]: Skipping plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/nrdp.py) as it seems to be invalid: from_buffer() cannot return the address of the raw string
within a str or unicode or bytearray object
[WARNING]: Skipping plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/slack.py) as it seems to be invalid: from_buffer() cannot return the address of the raw string
within a str or unicode or bytearray object
[WARNING]: Skipping plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/splunk.py) as it seems to be invalid: from_buffer() cannot return the address of the raw string
within a str or unicode or bytearray object
[WARNING]: Skipping plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/sumologic.py) as it seems to be invalid: from_buffer() cannot return the address of the raw string
within a str or unicode or bytearray object
```

Why this happen, and how can I remove this warning?

Server params:
ansible version - 2.9
OS version - Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

It look like Python 2 deprecation.

```
ansible --version
```

if you get

```
python version = 2.x.x (…)
```

You should change ansible runtime to Python 3.

Changing ansible runtime is quite complicated, safer is upgrade OS to version which support Python 3 only.
But it could be also difficult, if you need use any other Python2-depend software.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59716485/ansible-how-to-change-python-version